I can create new objects that are visible in the viewport but can't select them. They are invisible in the outliner
Please someone help me. I'm to the point that I feel like crying.
I am able to create new objects in the viewport, this cube for example, but cannot select or manipulate them at all, and they do not exist in my outliner.
This began after entering weight paint mode in the attempts to create stylized hair physics by following a tutorial.. after realizing the issue that I'm facing I tried ctrl+z but couldn't go back far enough to correct whatever happened. For some reason there was an "amongus" annotation in my scene.. I have since deleted all of my vertex groups. Everything else in my scene is fine.
I'm freaking out, please help.


Added an answer. If none of this helps, please [edit] your question and add further details of your situation, especially screenshots of your while outliner and viewport. Why not even share your file in addition to screenshots.

Are you sure you are in object mode?

You switched to weight paint mode to paint weights, but have you switched back to object mode in order to move objects around?
As for the "objects that do not exist in the outliner", perhaps you didn't add new objects, but instead added new meshes while being in edit mode inside an existing mesh object? Or your outliner is set to a display mode that doesn't show your current scene's content.
